# Concatenating byte arrays in Jni android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI and trying to muddle my way through. Please can someone point me in the direction to do the following in JNI. I am a bit out of my depth here, Can JNI handle Byte Arrays. Also were is the best places to find JNI examples.

This is the JAVA code I want to convert

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
outputStream.write(key1);
outputStream.write(key2);
byte[] key3 = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Thank you in advance

Rob

Comment: Of course JNI can handle byte arrays. This looks straightforward to write using JNI. What do you have now and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Ha .. nothing .. still trying to find my way around JNI. a bit overwhelming. Working with Strings at the moment trying to understand how to send and get back results

Comment: Don't know about example, but the documentation of all available functions [is here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html). From there you can just search for the type of data you want to work with (e.g. "ByteArray") and see what comes up.

Comment: Ok I see I have to use memcpy.. Will look up that

Comment: You can literally translate the Java code to a series of JNI calls and not have to worry about memcpy or allocating memory.

Comment: Thanks Botje Still trying to work out how to pass Byte array to JNI and back public native Byte enc(Byte[]a, Byte[]b);

Comment: Note that `Byte[]` (array of `java.lang.Byte` objects) is very different from `byte[]` (byte array). JNI has a `jbytearray` type to receive the latter.

Comment: Getting there .. just not sure how to join them now
    
    jbyte *z = (jbyte *)env->GetByteArrayElements(a, NULL);
    jbyte *x = (jbyte *)env->GetByteArrayElements(b, NULL);

Answer (score 1):

Here is a literal translation of the Java code you posted:

```
jclass cls_BAOS = env->FindClass("java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream");
jmethodID ctr_BAOS = env->GetMethodID(cls_BAOS, "<init>", "()V");
jobject baos = env->NewObject(cls_BAOS, ctr_BAOS);

jmethodID mid_BAOS_writeBytes = env->GetMethodID(cls_BAOS, "writeBytes", "([B)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(baos, mid_BAOS_writeBytes, key1);
env->CallVoidMethod(baos, mid_BAOS_writeBytes, key2);

jmethodID mid_BAOS_toByteArray = env->GetMethodID(cls_BAOS, "toByteArray", "()[B");
jbyteArray key3 = (jbytearray)env->CallObjectMethod(baos, mid_BAOS_toByteArray);
```

And here is an implementation that uses lower-level operations:

```
jsize key1len = env->GetArrayLength(key1);
jsize key2len = env->GetArrayLength(key2);
jbyteArray key3 = env->NewByteArray(key1+key2);

{
  jbyte *key1ptr = env->GetByteArrayElements(key1, nullptr);
  env->SetByteArrayRegion(key3, 0, key1len, key1ptr);
  env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(key1, key1ptr, JNI_ABORT);
}
{
  jbyte *key2ptr = env->GetByteArrayElements(key2, nullptr);
  env->SetByteArrayRegion(key3, key1len, key2len, key2ptr);
  env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(key2, key2ptr, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

You could also `memcpy` both byte arrays to a single C++ array first and then use a single call to `SetByteArrayRegion` or anything else really, but what's the point? The Java code was simple and readable and all of this JNI code is just adding pointless obfuscation.

Comment: Ahhhh .. Goodie .. Ok now I can see where to go .. Thank you Botje.. You are a real expert and i come across ur name wrt JNI all the time

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Botje, this is the final code that works.

```
    jclass cls_BAOS = env->FindClass("java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream");
    jmethodID ctr_BAOS = env->GetMethodID(cls_BAOS, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject baos = env->NewObject(cls_BAOS,ctr_BAOS);

    jmethodID mid_BAOS_writeBytes = env->GetMethodID(cls_BAOS, "writeBytes", "([B)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(baos, mid_BAOS_writeBytes, a);
    env->CallVoidMethod(baos, mid_BAOS_writeBytes, b);

    jmethodID mid_BAOS_toByteArray = env->GetMethodID(cls_BAOS, "toByteArray", "()[B");
    jbyteArray key3 = (jbyteArray)env->CallObjectMethod(baos, mid_BAOS_toByteArray);
```

Comment: I fixed the one wrong line in my answer. Please mark that as accepted instead of posting your a self-answer.